# Javascript and "div" Tags

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to change the background color of a div style by an JavaScript "if" routine, unfotunatly i get an error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null "

```
  <head>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
       <style type="text/css">
            .ok{ background-color:green; }
            .dead{ background-color:red; }
        </style>

 <script type="text/javascript">


function emea(){


    if (<?php echo $variable;?>==1) {


      document.getElementById('test').className = 'ok';
    }
    else {

      document.getElementById('test').className = 'dead';
    }
}

emea(); 
    </script>

 </head>

<div id="test">BlaBla</div>
```

Comment: _javascript_, not _java script_. It has nothing to do with java.

Comment: *i'd like to change the background color of a div style by an javascript "if" routine:* OK. What's the problem?

Comment: Why the opening PHP tag?

Comment: Take a moment...breathe...now ask the question again and pay attention to your formatting...

Comment: you forgot the dots on your class selectors in the css (.ok, .dead).

Comment: What does `<?php $variable==1` do there? This is a very straightforward problem and your example is basically lacking everything. Please be aware that such questions will not be well received on SO, as this is a platform intended for _professional_ programmers.

Comment: man, you guys are animals with the downvotes.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart: we SO guys are animals with upvotes too....it depends on the question/post

Comment: You should really avoid mixing php and Javascript that way. Go and read about REST architecture it will help you create better designs. I don't think this deserves downvotes nor SO is for professionnal programmers only. There are a lot of people thinking they are great programmers because they are on SO. We all start somewhere and SO is a good place to start. I've been blindly downvoted too at the beggining. Just read more about your languages and you will figure it out. Programming properly is very hard at the beggining.

Comment: @dirkk No it isn't; it's a platform for ["professional and enthusiast programmers"](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Professional" is well-defined.

Comment: @DaveNewton You say "No", but I have no idea what you are referring to as this is exactly what I said. I just left out "and enthusiast" as I try to keep comments short and it wasn't really relevant.

Comment: @dirkk Obviously it's not exactly what you said, and you just said it wasn't?! I believe your emphasis on "professional" was off-putting. If you wanted to keep your comment short, try instead removing the words that add nothing to your comment, instead of stating only professionals are welcome here, e.g., "This is a straightforward problem and your example lacks details. Such questions are not well received on SO." Shorter. Better. Doesn't misrepresent. YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you were close you just need to take a little more time checking your formatting...

There are a lot of unanswered questions here but this is what you were shooting for, I think.

```
<head>

<style type="text/css">
.ok
{ 
    background-color:green; 
}

.dead
{ 
    background-color:red; 
}
</style>

<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var variable1 = '<?php echo($variable1); ?>';

function emea()
{
    if(variable1 !== '')
    {
        document.getElementById('test').className = 'dead';
    }
    else
    {   
        document.getElementById('test').className = 'ok';
    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="emea();">

<div id="test">BlaBla</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to ask why not just use PHP to change the div's class?

```
<div id="test" class="<?php echo ($variable == 1) ? 'ok' : 'dead'; ?>"></div>
```

If you have to use javascript then there is no real need for the 'else' clause as the classname .dead is the default class:

```
var phpVar = <?php echo $variable; ?>;

if (phpvar == 1) 
    document.getElementById('test').className = 'ok';
```

Then just set the default class in the html:

Also, I notice you have jQuery included in your example, and your question wasn't specific enough to say if you are actually using it or not. If you are, then you can use:

```
$('#test').prop('class', 'ok')
```

I would stick with the pure JS version however is it is almost 4 times faster: http://jsperf.com/jquery-addclass-vs-attr-class-vs-prop-class

Comment: PHP is just an example. The code is on a webserver of a PLC and there i can just ca use a ASP Tag like <% ReadPLC("Variable");%>, so have use Javascript. I can not use any "If,then,else,while....".